# Express.js 3beta or 2.x?

Tags: session, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm still trying to learn node.js + express.js to make something...
But after many days reading old docs and "converting" them to new express I've just found out that the Express 3.0 beta is, as it seams, very unstable, and of course very, very bad documented.
So, the thing is, I don't know why the default install in npm is the 3.0 if it's unstable, all I need to know is if 3.0 can handle(without having to right all the libraries by my self):

**Session, authentication and socket.io.**

I at least those working to make my project, but if 3.0 can't handle it, is it better for me to stay with 2.x?

Thanks for the help, I'm almost giving up on this framework, it's been too frustrating to learn it =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used express v2.5.8 the last time I used node & express - I ran into some issues with express 3.0 (alpha) and reverted to 2.+ and bypassed issues that will pop up with any new release.
I would suggest that you wait for a more stable 3.0 release.  Till then,  just use node/socket.io etc with express 2.+.